# first() don't seem to work while using an image transform

Tags: assets, image-transforms, loop

This "standard" set-up for rendering asset transforms works as expected.

```
                {% set image = entry.articleImages %}

                {% if image | length %}
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="work">

                            {% for asset in image %}
                                <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('worksList') }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" title="{{ asset.title }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight('worksList') }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth('worksList') }}">
                            {% endfor %}

                        </a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
```

When I only want the first image out of the assets loop I would normally add .first() to the set image loop.

```
{% set image = entry.articleImages.first() %}
```

However this ends op in unclear error messages while rendering on the front-end ( Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a string variable ("111"))!
Or am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 1):

This is where it goes wrong:

```
{% for asset in image %}
```

Because you use `first()`, you end up with an AssetFileModel, not an array of those.
If you than loop through that AssetFileModel with a for-loop, you get all the values of that Model. They don't have a method called getUrl(), which is what causes the error.

So, skip the for-loop and just use:

```
{% set image = entry.articleImages.first() %}
<img src="{{ asset.url('worksList') }}" />
```

The `url()` method is [an alias](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel#url) for `getUrl()`.

Comment: Exactly that did the job, with one minor change: <img src="{{ image.url('worksList') }}"> Thanks

Comment: Could you please accept the answer, then? And maybe tell me what the change was, so other users can learn from it ...